# Get all overlapping matches of any length

Tags: ruby, regex, match, overlapping-matches

I'm trying to achieve:

```
'abc'.scan(regex) #=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'bc', 'abc']
```

It can be done like this:

```
(1..'abc'.size).map {|l| 'abc'.scan /(?=(\w{#{l}}))/}.flatten
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc"]
```

But I would like to do it in one regex expression.

Answer (score 3):

What about without regex?:

```
string = 'abc'
p (1..string.size).flat_map { |e| string.chars.each_cons(e).map(&:join) }
# ["a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc"]
```

Comment: This works, but `each_cons` eventually gets called with `4` in this example, which is too high. You should modify the code to use `(1..string.size)` and `each_cons(e)` instead. I also suggest renaming `|e|` to `|substr_length|` for clarity.

Comment: `combination(e)` instead of `each_cons(e)` works too.

Comment: @SagarPandya That includes "ac".

Comment: Very minor: I suggest `each_char` rather than `chars` to avoid an unneeded temporary array.

Comment: No, what I'm interested in is if there is a method or a Regex functionality to find overlapping matches of all possible lengths

Comment: Asone, you certainly cannot do that with a single regex combined with a method like `String#scan`.  Regular expressions are simply not designed to do that sort of thing. With regards to a "method" that does that, do you mean a built-in method? (After all Sebatian could wrap what he has in a method.) If you mean a built-in method, it would have to be an instance method of the class `String`. Go through those methods and you won't find any that even come close to what you want to do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, that's exactly what I was asking (It's really more of a regex question than a ruby question). It's a shame there's no nicer way to do it.